# useReducer not updating the initialState when used with useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form, which has to be pre-populated with some value. These values come from context. I am using a reducer to handle the state of the form, so I set the initial state of the reducer from what I get from the context. Now what is happening is the context changes but the reducer state doesn't change.

```
const { selectedCurrency } =
        useContext<CurrenciesContextType>(CurrenciesContext);

const [state, dispatch]: [CurrencyReducerState, Dispatch<any>] = useReducer(
    currencyReducer as ReducerWithoutAction<CurrencyReducerState>,
    selectedCurrency,
    init
);
```

Ideally, whenever the selectedCurrency changes, it should set the initial values. But it doesn't happen. Any idea why?. I have wrapped the parent component inside the provider. Also every time the selectedCurrency changes, I see the selectedCurrency changing but the reducer state doesn't change. If the component is re-rendered then the reducer picks up the changes and initializes correctly.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The third param init is a function, where is that function  defined ? init is termed as Lazy initialization, i am not able to find the snippet from question posted

Comment: @Learner `const init = (state)=>({...INITIAL_STATE, ...state});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this behaviour by adding a updateState action in my reducer and wrapping this action inside useEffect with selectedCurrency as its dependency :

```
useEffect(() => {
    actions.updateState(selectedCurrency)
}, [selectedCurrency])
```

here is what the action looks like :

```
updateState: (updatedState): void => 
    dispatch({type: "update", payload: updatedState})
```

The **init()** function is executed only once when the **useReducer** is first called.

Similar question -
[Updating useReducer 'state' using useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364364/updating-usereducer-state-using-useeffect)

Answer (score 0):

Without more example code, it's hard to tell, but maybe you're forgetting to wrap your code with the context provider?  The code that needs to use the context (objects and/or callbacks) needs to be wrapped in the provider.

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    {/* CurrenciesProvider enables children to use the context info */ } 
    <CurrenciesProvider>
      <CurrencySelector />
      <CurrencyDisplay />
    </CurrenciesProvider>
  </div>
);
```

Here's a codesandbox...
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-noether-zr9dq

Comment: I have wrapped the parent component inside the provider. Also every time the selectedCurrency changes, I see the selectedCurrency changing but the reducer state doesn't change. If the component is re-rendered then the reducer picks up the changes and initializes correctly.

Comment: Then post a codesandbox demoing the problem. It’ll be easier to help fix if you show an example where it fails.

Comment: Basically, I want to reinitialize my reducer's initial state whenever there's a change in the context variable. is it possible?